# Create UIButton and add it on multiple UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I would like to create one UIButton and add it on multiple UIView but it doesn't work like this :

```
UIButton *myBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 44.0f)];
[myBtn setTitle:@"MyButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIView *myView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[myView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 50.0f)];
[myView1 addSubview:myBtn];

UIView *myView2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[myView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 100.0f)];
[myView2 addSubview:myBtn];
```

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can't add the same instance on more UIViews. When you add it on the second view, the button will be removed from the first view. You will need to have an instance for each view where where you'll add it.